# Initialize tabbarcontroller from scenedelgate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have changed my initial ViewController using scenedelegate.swift. Now I want to initialize tabbar controller from scenedelegate.swift.

```
    guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Home")
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

[Home.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxOYH.png)

Comment: It's the same process as you've already done for your initialViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UITabBarController subclass and assign it to a TabBar controller with a storyboard identifier. And then,

```
 guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TabBarController")
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I tried your method, It worked, but a white empty space appears in the top of my view controller. Here is my storyboard hierarchy. i.stack.imgur.com/SxOYH.png. I tried to set visible false in viewwillappear function,, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    private let storyboardName = "Main"
    private let tabbarControllerIdentifier = "TabBarController"
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: tabbarControllerIdentifier)
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarController)
        
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```